# How to avoid using Vue.set() within external js class files preserving reactivity for nested object properties?

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity

I have this component:

```
<template>
    <div class="simple-editor">
        {{editor.view.toolbarManager.buttons}}
        <component
            v-for="(button, name) in editor.view.toolbarManager.buttons" 
            :is="button.component" 
            :options="button.options"
            :key="name"
        ></component></div>
//.......................
```

I am trying to use `editor.view.toolbarManager.buttons` within `v-for` loop. Vue devtools shows me (for all 3 cases bellow) that `editor.view.toolbarManager.buttons` is an Object and contains 4 properties which contains another object.

```
<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
    return {
        editor: new Editor({
            doc: this.value,
            init: this.init,
        }),
    }
    },
```

`editor.view.toolbarManager.buttons` is filling in within subclasses of `Editor()` class with dynamically imported scripts like this:

```
props.plugins.forEach(plugin => {
    this.plugins[plugin] = import(/* webpackMode: "eager" */ '../plugin/' + plugin);
});
```

I fill in `editor.view.toolbarManager.buttons` like this:

```
// case 1: works fine as expected
Vue.set(this.buttons, name, {
    component,
    options,
});     

/* case 2: loses vue reactivity
var button = {};

button[name] = {
    component,
    options,
};

Object.assign(this.buttons, button);
*/

/* case 3: loses vue reactivity
this.buttons[name] = {
    component,
    options,
};
*/
```

The issue is next: when I try to render `{{editor.view.toolbarManager.buttons}}` within template I see empty object for cases 2 and 3 like this:

> {}

which means vue reactivity is broken. `Editor()` is external class and I don't want to tie it to Vue. Vue reactivity is fine for within external classes for arrays because of using splice/push methods. Does exist a similar methods for object properties with preserving Vue reactivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! I have messed up with `Object.assign()`. This is a right using of `Object.assign()` instead of `Vue.set()`:

```
var button = {};

button[name] = {
    component,
    options,
};

this.buttons = Object.assign({}, this.buttons, button);
```

This works fine for me. And documentation is here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects :

> ```
> // instead of `Object.assign(this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })`
> this.someObject = Object.assign({}, this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })
> ```